# Why do I get XR Plug-in Management Error when I tried assigning ARCore in XR Plug-in Management in Unity2020?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am new to Unity3d software, and I was researching AR apps for a project, and decided to test the waters myself before heading on to the actual project. I installed the software, downloaded Vuforia package for Unity and integrated into it, selected and installed my build settings for Android, then went into the Unity Registry inside the package manager, and installed AR Foundation and ARCore Plug-ins. After installing them, I went into XR Plug-in Manager and under Android, I tried checking the ARCore box, but it wouldn't let me and displayed the following error:

```
XR Plug-in Management error. Failure reason: Unable to assign com.unity.xr.arcore for build target Android..
 Check if there are any other errors in the console and make sure they are corrected before trying again.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

Here is the screenshot for what I was referring to
[image: Here is the screenshot for what I was referring to]

I would appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to quickly test the waters, I recommend ar foundation. ar foundation is unity's api for both ar core (Android) and ar kit (iOS)
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/setting-up-ar-foundation
A good place to start with AR foundation is this repo...
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples
Simply download it and use it as the basis for your project. It has Ar foundation setup + has a bunch of example scenes.
You can just download it, open in unity, build to device and be messing with the AR foundation features in 10 mins.

The benefit of AR foundation is it is cross platform (works on iOS and Android)
This project does not include vuforia, but I dont see why you'd want Ar foundation *and* vuforia. They both do the same thing roughly afaik.